# How can we implement soft delete on cgridview?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

This is my cgridview.Here view,update,delete works fine. but I want to impliment soft deletion . so how can i customize the delete button here?

```
<div id="status" style="display:none;margin-left:450px;margin-top:25px;"></div>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'printstatusforlocal-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
'order_id',
'albumname',
'username',
'usermail',
'bookid',
array('header'=> 'No. of Pages',
'name'=>'noofpages',
'value'=>$model->noofpages,
),
array('header'=> 'Order Date',
'name'=>'orderdate',
'value'=>$model->orderdate,
                ),
array('header'=> 'Synchronized',
'name'=>'synchronize',
'value'=>'$data->Syncronize',
                ),
array(
 'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
),),
)); 
?>
</div> <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Help me please..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate action and set the url of the delete button using [`deleteButtonUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#deleteButtonUrl-detail):

```
...
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'deleteButtonUrl' => 'array("controller/action", "id" => "$data->id")'
),),
```